# Embed parameter in another parameter name in teamcity

Tags: teamcity

An example:
I am using autoinc feature in teamcity so whenever I change the version of my build I would like to change it only in one place.

```
%buildversion% is 5.0
```

so I would like to do the following:

```
%autoinc.buildname_%buildversion%%
```

to get `%autoinc.buildname_5.0%.`
Basically every time I change the version autoinc counter will be reseted.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Paraemters
[image: Create the Paraemters]

Create a Combined Paramter
[image: Create a Combined Paramter]

Comment: this is not what I was after. The result is i.e 1.0_5.0 but I want %autoinc.buildname_5.0% so autoinc parameter should append version to its name

Comment: Misunderstood what you were asking for. I updated the answer.

Comment: Updated version produces similar result to the one before. I want to have this:
%autoinc.buildname_{another parameter here}% so it would take parameter i.e  %autoinc.buildname_5.0% and convert it to the 0,1,2,3. So whenever I change the version it should restart the counter

Comment: So you want to embed a parameter within the another parameter? Why not create a different parameter that combines both parameters that you want?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I have these parameters in my root project. And the way teamcity work it puts every parameter into build so autoinc is evaluated with every build so if I store autoinc in root project, all of them will be incremented with every single build. That's why I had to put it in build configuration itself. Not sure if I understand, can you provide an example?

Comment: I see your edit but
a) It doesn't solve the problem because I have to share 'combined param' in i.e 2 builds. And I need to do it for multiple number of pairs. If I put it in parent project of these builds then every combined param will be incremented and this is not something I want.
b) AutoInc part should change the name so the counter should be resetted to 0. Your solution won't help here.

The main goal is to whenever I changed param 'Aversion' it should reset all autoinc counters where 'Aversion' is used. (Not sure if you are aware that autoinc is a special feature in tc)

Comment: So you want Aversion to always stay the same per project? Defined it globally, then override it for each project build paramters with the value you want. Then leave the Autoinc (which is a TC plugin by the way, not built into TC) configured per project. That will might get you partially there, but from reading about that plugin, it stores the properties globally, so not sure you can do what you are asking without some custom powershell step. I did something similar with resetting the build counter to 0 for each day, but that required me storing it somewhere and setting it myself.